# white space free path to My Documents

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu

In building a C++ project with the GNU tool chain, make tells me ~

> src/Adapter_FS5HyDE.d:1: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

Search, search, search, and I found out that `make` *thinks* that it has multiple targets because the path to my included headers has spaces in it.  If you've got your headers stored in some *sane* place  like `C:\Program Files` then you can take care of this by using the old DOS paths (e.g. `C:\PROGRA~1`).  However, when you have your headers in a truly insane place like `My Documents` you can get around the problem with `MY DOC~1` because there's still a space.

Any idea how to tell my compiler to look in My Documents for headers without `make` confusing the path as two objects?

(Note: Feel free to throw tomatoes at me for putting header files in My Documents if you'd like, but there *is* a little rationale for doing that which I don't feel like explaining.  If the solution to this question is easy, I'd rather keep it the way it is.)

Comment: Shortened names don't usually have spaces. Are you _sure_ that `MY DOC~1` is really the short name of your `My Documents` folder?

Comment: My "My Documents" folder has a short alias of "MYDOCU~1". I agree with Charles Bailey - it's unusual for a 8.3 short alias of a long filename to contain a space. If they contained spaces that would defeat the reasons Microsoft came up with that kludge. Something strange has happened on your system.

Comment: Could you go to the parent of the "My Documents" directory, do a "dir /x" command and paste the output (at least the relevant line) into your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can figure out what the old path is by doing a `DIR /X` in your command prompt.

Or, most of the time you can fake it with the first 6 characters - spaces + `~1` + extension (8.3 paths won't have spaces).

Or, you can use quotes: `"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents"`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about make specficially, but the normal way around this is to put quotes around the path i.e.

```
cd "C:\Program Files\"
```

does that work?

Comment: It doesn't in Makefile targets and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

**Side note**: the short name (8.3) for the same folder might not be the same on different OS installations. Thus, you can't be sure that `C:\Program Files` will always be `C:\PROGRA~1`.

- Short names can't contain spaces in them either, so the usual short name for `My Documents` is `MYDOCU~1`, not `MY DOC~1`.
- You can find the exact short name for any folder or file (including `My Documents`) using `dir /x <filename>`.
- If you are using the GNU toolchain from Windows command line (`cmd.exe`), you should be able to use quotes (`"`) around the folder/file names to work around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For some folders, including My Documents, you can specify an alternative location. To do this, right-click the folder, select Properties, select Location tab, and away you go. I use this to put my downloads and music on another drive (D:).

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper script (e.g. batchfile) to translate the path names to short form.

I have a script "runwin" that does stuff like this - instead of, e.g. `gcc <args>`  I can call `runwin gcc <args>`;
runwin will make heuristic guesses as to which arguments are filename paths and translate them, then call gcc on the resulting string of arguments.